# QUARKUS: get aws secret from secretsmanager as environnement variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, quarkus, secretsmanager

how to get secret as **environnement variable** from **aws secretsmanager** by quarkus extension :

```
io.quarkiverse.amazonservices:quarkus-amazon-secretsmanager
```

Comment: Overriding `System.getenv()` isn't very easy.  Is it too much trouble to convert?

Comment: I mean like spring boot with spring cloud, it's possible out of the box just a bootstrap.properties file with aws.secretsmanager.enabled=true

Answer (score 0):

Try this way It may work...
In application properties

```
quarkus.amazon-secrets-manager.credentials.provider=env
quarkus.amazon-secrets-manager.credentials.env.access-key-id={}
quarkus.amazon-secrets-manager.credentials.env.access-key={}
quarkus.amazon-secrets-manager.region={}
```

then in class you can use @ConfigProperty annotation to retrieve the value

```java
@ConfigProperty(name="secret_key")
String secretKey
```

reference
https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-amazon-services/dev/amazon-secretsmanager.html